# prove that $\operatorname{Ker}T=\operatorname{Im}(S)^\perp$ for some transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**
Let $V$ be an inner product space of finite dimension. Given linear transformations $T,S\colon V \to V$ such that $\langle T(v),w\rangle=\langle v,S(w)\rangle$, for all $v,w \in V$. Show that $\operatorname{Ker}T=(\operatorname{Im}S)^{\perp}$

**Thought of a proof:**
Let $w \in V$, $k \in \operatorname{Ker}T$. Therefore
$\langle T(k),w\rangle=\langle k,S(w)\rangle$
and $\langle 0,w\rangle=\langle k,S(w)\rangle$ so $0=\langle k,S(w)\rangle$.

Therefore $k$ is orthogonal to every $w\in V$ and so $k \in (\operatorname{Im}S)^\perp$.

Is this direction true?

Comment: yes i didn't know how to write it

Comment: Anyway, you want to say that $k$ is orthogonal to $S(w)$ for every $w \in V$. Other than that, your proof looks good. How about the other direction? I think it's the trickier of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Note that one usually denotes the orthogonal by $(\mbox{Im } S)^\perp$. So you have proved that $\mbox{Ker T}\subseteq (\mbox{Im } S)^\perp$. Note also $S$, as it is defined, is called the adjoint of $T$ and is denoted by $S=T^*$.

For the other direction, you could use dimension, noting that both subspaces have the same dimension.

For a proof working in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, assuming $T$ is bounded, you could use that $V=\mbox{Ker } T\oplus (\mbox{Ker } T)^\perp$. Then take $x=k\oplus l$ decomposed according to this orthogonal decomposition and assume that $x$ lies in $(\mbox{Im } S)^\perp$. Then $0=(x,Sy)=(Tx,y)=(Tk+Tl,y)=(Tl,y)$ for every $y\in V$. This implies that $Tl=0$, so $l$ is in $\mbox{Ker } T\cap (\mbox{Ker } T)^\perp$. Hence $l=0$ and $x=k+l=k$ belongs to $\mbox{Ker } T$.